# Defining my dataset in Pytorch before defining a train & test nn

Tags: python, pytorch, label, tensorflow-datasets

So I have an assignment and I think I understand everything that's required, except for the initialisation of my data. I have a folder structure with lots of directories, each containing opseq codes. There is a Benign folder with 1000 samples and spread across all the other folders is another 1000 samples. How do I set up the data in Pytorch so that I have one dataset with the Opseq codes labelled as either Malware or Benign?

The code that I have been given to start with seems to just print a list of all the Opseq codes with a 1 appended to them if they don't reside in the Benign folder and a 0 appended to them if they do, but how do I consolidate this into one dataset with two labels, with each Opseq code being assigned one of the two labels?

```
import torch
import os
import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset


import pdb
#import test_cases

def read_file(filename):
    opcode_seq = []
    opcode_count = 0
    with open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        for c in range(0,len(line) - 1,2):
            #print(line[c:(c+2)],int(line[c:(c+2)], 16))
            opcode_seq.append(int(line[c:(c+2)], 16) + 1) # add one here so that the zero'th embedding is reserved for 'blank' i.e. no instruction whatsoever not even no-op            
            opcode_count += 1
            # to save training time we only read 
            # the first opt.max_opcode_seq_len opcodes of each file
            if opcode_count >= max_opcode_seq_len:
                return opcode_seq
            
    #pad with zeros between methods        
    if opcode_count < max_opcode_seq_len:
        for i in range (opcode_count+1, max_opcode_seq_len+1):
            opcode_seq.append(0)
    return opcode_seq

def read_dataset(dir, verbose = True):
    malware = []
    clean = []
    min_file_len = min_opcode_seq_len #ignore opcode seq files shorter than this
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            if os.path.split(root)[-1] == 'Benign':
                if (name.endswith('.b') or name.endswith('.opseq')) and (not name.startswith('._')):
                    if verbose:
                        print('0',os.path.join(root,name))
                    #labels.append(1)
                    tmp = read_file(os.path.join(root,name))
                    if len(tmp) >= min_file_len:
                        clean.append(tmp)
            else:
                if verbose:
                    print('1',os.path.join(root,name))
                if name.endswith('.opseq') and (not name.startswith('._')):
                    #labels.append(0)
                    tmp = read_file(os.path.join(root,name))
                    if len(tmp) >= min_file_len:
                        malware.append(tmp)
    return malware,clean

max_opcode_seq_len=8192
min_opcode_seq_len=32
dataset_root = './malwarecw'
malware,clean = read_dataset(dataset_root)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to implement your own Dataset class.
I'd suggest you to have a look in the PyTorch documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#Dataset

and to the PyTorch tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/custom_dataset_transforms_loader.html?highlight=dataset

Comment: Thanks for that, and I have looked there, but don't seem to be able (and I could be really thick) to find an easy way to assign labels to data. I'll keep searching.

Comment: I see. Another possible way is to pre-compute the labels. In the __init__ of the dataset class you could instantiate 2 lists of path-to-file and label associated to this path. In this way, in the __getitem()__ you have to access to the path given the index, load the file and select the corresponding label from the list.